# Tshark interface to sniff on

Tags: ubuntu, wireshark, mqtt, tshark, wireshark-dissector

I have a MQTT broker and a MQTT client both running on the same machine. The client sends publish packets to the broker. The broker processes it and sends it back to the same client as publish packet.

I want to use tshark to capture the MQTT packets and by doing this I want to calculate how much time did it take for the packet to reach the broker once it was sent of by the client i.e. time spent in the transport layer.

***1) I am not able to decide as to which interface should I sniff on using tshark ?***

***2) Secondly, I wanted to know if there is a better way to accomplish this task ?***

Comment: This question is better suited for [SuperUser](http://superuser.com) or [ServerFault](http://serverfault.com).

Answer (score 0):

Which interface to listen on will depend on how you have configured your broker and client.

Assuming you have bound the broker to all addresses (using something like 0.0.0.0) and you have told the client to connect to localhost then you would want to listen on the loopback lo0 adapter.

As for measuring the time in the network stack, for a loopback connection this is going to be minimal as it all takes place in memory. Also your only going to see the packet once, as it "travels" between the client and broker, so there will be no way to really see how long it takes.

Comment: my broker listens on the port 8081 and I have a MQTT client built using nodejs. The client spawns multiple instances of itself to simulate concurrent connects and publishes to the broker. Both, the client and the broker are on the same machine. I did use tshark to capture on lo0 adapter however it only picks up TCP packets. It does not pick up any MQTT packets.

Comment: The MQTT protocol flows over TCP/IP, it may just be that the version tshark you have does not have a MQTT decoder. There is one available for Wireshark (https://www.wireshark.org/docs/dfref/m/mqtt.html)